# PostgreSQL full text search words delimiter

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

Please help me to understand how to change words delimiter when I use gin index. The problem is that "," ";" and " " signs are words delimiters but the "." isn't. So in phrase "Some 11.22.33.44 IP" I am able to find "Some" "11.22.33.44" "IP" words. When I am looking for "33" - unable to find it. Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The "natural" way to do this would be to change or write your own text search parser.  While it is possible to do that, it is unreasonably difficult.

Do you want both '11.22.33.44' and '33' to show up as individual tokes, or just '33'?  If the latter, then maybe just preprocess your data by replacing all '.' with ' ':

```
replace(doc,'.',' ')
```

Of course you should do the same replacement on the queries as well before passing them to `plainto_tsquery`.

Comment: Thank you for response. I just want 11 22 33 44 to be separate words. I just have no idea why "." as end of the sentence isn't words separator.

Comment: The "." you show is not at the end of a sentence.

Comment: Yes, sure. That's the point. I just want to change the behavior.